# Selecting ranges of Unicode in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, unicode

I am trying to select a range of Unicode characters from a column. Lets say I am trying to select one of the ranges below. Is this possible in SQL using something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE col1 LIKE UNICODE(3000 - 303f)
```

Japanese-style punctuation ( 3000 - 303f)

Hiragana ( 3040 - 309f)

Katakana ( 30a0 - 30ff)

I haven't seen anything like this so it might not be possible but if it is, just a pointer in the right direction of an answer would be great.

If more info is needed please ask.

Comment: What are you trying to determine? Whether it contains any character in that range? What it only contains characters from within that range? Something else? Seems like the sort of thing that could be checked using regexes more easily, but since SQL Server still doesn't expose regex directly in T-SQL, unlikely that support for this exists.

Comment: I am searching a column that "should" only contain one range of Unicode, but in reality contains other ranges, as well as numbers and English characters. So instead of coding in every character I was wondering if there was a different way to do it. I know its a bit of a longshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `unicode()` or `nchar()` functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE UNICODE(LEFT(col1, 1)) BETWEEN 0x3000 AND 0x303F
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that will only compare the first character. Based on the OP's comment on question, it seems they want to validate that all characters in a column belong to a particular range.

Comment: Is that what the '1' does? Just checks the first character? To be honest that does help return the results I need. Thanks.

Comment: @JimmyPop13 . . . Yes, this just checks the first character.